# how to get move direction using acceleometer and gps in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to get move direction accurately in my android app. using accelenometer and GPS I do not know how much it is possible to get by using accelenometer and GPS
please help me

Comment: why don't ypu use loctaion.getHeading() ? (or sometimes called getBearing())

Answer (score 1):

Try reading tutorials in the android.developer website. You can begin from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html)

*Also try not to post questions that are incomplete and already answered. Happy coding .